# Turn expectation values back into classical data

Tags: quantum-state, machine-learning

How are expectation values turned back into classical data for evaluation?

I have a circuit performing a regression task that returns the expectation value of the Pauli Z operator. I would like to know how if this expval can be converted back to its classical data format to evaluate the prediction values (hopefully coming from the expvals) side by side with the labels.

In other words, what is the process in a quantum circuit in order to translate the output expectation values to their classical format so they can be evaluated?

Is there a quantum to classical (Q2C) transformation that allows one to see the embedded classical value in the quantum state expectation values?

Thank you.

Comment: an expectation value *is* classical data. You obtain it computing a linear combination of (estimated) output probabilities.

Comment: Does [this Q/A](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/34239/calculating-the-expectation-value-after-mid-circuit-measurements-in-qiskit/34243#34243) answer your question?

Comment: The quantum circuit returns a prediction value represented in expectation values that show the data in its quantum state. The question is, is there a quantum to classical (Q2C) transformation that allows one to see the embedded classical value in the quantum state expectation values?

Comment: @camaya I'm still not sure what you mean. You measure, estimate probabilities from counts, and from those possibly compute expectation values of whatever observables you care about. What does "classical data" mean for you? Do you perhaps have some specific application in mind, such as a specific embedding of classical information into the quantum state? If that's what you mean, you should clarify the specific context, because the way you embed data very much affects how you'd get it back